# Access 2010: JOIN tables and return the most recent record

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to work out how to get the right results from the following.

I am trying to create an Access query that takes the relevant staff rate to calculate a cost for an employee from timesheet data. The following is an example of the time data:

```
ID   EmpNo   Period_Month  Period_Year   CostCode   Workstage   Line_Hours
14   11486   3             2014          C10798     000         20.00
15   11486   3             2014          C10657     000         21.50
16   11486   3             2014          C11112     000         10.00
```

For this employee, there may be rates set during different periods as so:

```
EmpNo   Period_Month  Period_Year  Rate
11486   1             2014         10.00
11486   3             2014         12.00
11486   6             2014         15.00
```

I want to know how I can join the two tables to calculate a cost (hours * rate) and pick out only correct rate. A rate takes affect from the period it is stamped with and then-on until a new rate is entered. Normally in SQl I'd do this by taking the top item of an embedded select in the join but I can't seem to do the same in Access. I've also read that I could do a join on the rate table twice to pick up the item in the staff rate table that I require, but can't seem to apply the same logic to this.

**UPDATE**

As requested, the following is as far as i've got with the query. It gets me as far as all the rates for the current and previous periods, but I can't find a way to take the top one.

```
SELECT t.EmpNo, t.CostCode, t.Workstage, t.TimeCode_Desc, t.Line_Hours, t.Period_Month,   t.Period_Year, srA.Rate
FROM (tblTime AS t LEFT JOIN qryTotalHours AS hrs ON (t.Period_Year = hrs.Period_Year) AND (t.Period_Month = hrs.Period_Month) AND (t.EmpNo = hrs.EmpNo)) LEFT JOIN tblStaffRates AS srA ON t.EmpNo = srA.EmpNo
WHERE (((t.Period_Month)>=[srA].[Period_Month]));
```

Comment: What is your query like now?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265068/ms-access-latest-date-issue/23269839#23269839

Comment: I look at these and related articles. For some reason I'm not able to find anything consistent enough with this example to make them fit.